# How does one explain this worked example for determine the desired error in a series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Q:

Which partial sum estimates $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{(n+1)}\cdot n!} {n^n}$ with an error of at most four hundredths $(.04)$

A:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{(n+1)}\cdot\frac{n!}{n^n}$$

Error formula:
$$a_{j+1} < E_j \le .04$$

(Truncation error formula, where the first term is ignored)
So, we simple replace the original series with one MORE than the original sort of like the ratio test and carry out the algebra.

$$\frac{(j+1!)}{(j+1)^{(j+1)}} > .04$$

cross-multiply:

$$(j+1)\cdot j! < .04(j+1)^j\cdot(j+1)$$

$$j! < .04(j+1)^j$$

$$\frac{j!}{(j+1)^{j}} < .04\cdot\frac{(j+1)^j}{(j+1)^j}$$

$$\frac{j!}{(j+1)^j} < .04$$

Then for some reason we start plugging in value ONE after the first term, so at 2.

$$n = 2$$

$$\frac{2!}{3^2} < .04$$

$$n = 3$$

$$\frac{3!}{4^2} < .04$$

$$n = 4$$

$$\frac{4!}{5^3} < .04$$

$$n = 5$$

$$\frac{5!}{6^4} < .04$$

For some reason $n = 5$ is just right and this is the desired error,  or $n$ number of partial sums we would have to take in order to be within $.04$ error.

Can someone please explain if this is right.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like the work is right.  However, your denominators at the end look strange.

Comment: Thank you. How is the denominator off? please explain

Comment: Try checking what you should get when you plug $n=5$ in.  The denominator is still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your work is not right.  For an alternating series, you simply evaluate the magnitude of the j+1 term to obtain your error estimate.  You should not be looking at the ratio at all.   The ratio is useful for determining convergence not for estimating error.   So the expression to look at is just n!/(n^n).